# ActiveRecord conditional scopes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to create some kind of conditional scoping in my project, but can't figure out how to deal with that.

I have a medical practice and it's doctors.

```
    class Practice < ActiveRecord::Base
        has_many :doctors, -> { where removed_at: nil }
    end

    class Doctor < ActiveRecord::Base
        scope :with_all_doctors, -> {includes(:practice).where.not removed_at: nil}       
        belongs_to :practice
    end
```

Now I want to be able to find some practice and all it's doctors, as well as practice with only active doctors (removed_at == nil)

I'm trying to achieve something like:

```
    doctor = Doctor.find(id: params[:id]) #here we are fetching object hierarchy 
#with only active doctors of practice 
#(doctor.practice.doctors will give only active users)

    doctor = Doctor.with_all_doctors.find(id: params[:id]) #here we need to fetch object hierarchy 
#with all doctors of practice 
#(doctor.practice.doctors will give both active and removed doctors)
```

I would be very grateful for the solution.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are complicating your situation. Why not something like this?

```
class Practice < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :doctors
end

class Doctor < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :practice

  scope :active, -> { where :removed_at => nil }
  scope :inactive, -> { where("removed_at is not null") }
end
```

That way, you can do `docs = Practice.find(params[:id]).doctors` to get all the doctors and then `docs.active` or `docs.inactive` for the active and the inactive ones according to your needs.

Comment: Well, in real life I have deeper object hierarchy and I don't want to compose it manually. I need to get right structure and send it to client's app as json.

Comment: If you provide us with a "picture" of the hierarchy we can propose solutions for it too.

Comment: I think provided structure is enough (can't expose more because of NDA) for demonstration purposes. I just need a way to get desired structure without having to call scope directly on it's model object.